# CORS issue with PUT request with Angular 6

Tags: angular, cors

In my app, I have already made GET, POST, and DELETE requests successfully, but this is my first PUT query.
I also checked my API had no issue querying directly from the postman.

So, it appears it has to do with Angular, here is my code:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
};

export class TournamentService {
  update(tournament: Tournament, tab: string): Observable<any> {
      const tournamentUrl = this.tournamentsUrl + tournament.slug;
      console.log(tournamentUrl); // URL is OK
      return this.http.put(tournamentUrl, tournament, httpOptions).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateTournamentGeneral'))
      );
    }
  }
```

I get the CORS error message:

```
Failed to load https://api.kz-api.test/tournaments/fake-tournoi: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
Blocked current origin from receiving cross-site document at https://api.kz-api.test/tournaments/fake-tournoi with MIME type text/html.
```

But as for me, I explicitly ask for the MIME type to be `application/json`

Here is my Middleware code in Lumen on the API side:

```
class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Content-type' => 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'HEAD,GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => $request->header('Access-Control-Request-Headers')
        ];
        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS')) {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            $response->headers->set($key, $value);
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this one?

Comment: ok, first of all Postman will always work independently of CORS because it is an extension, it's a 'no-cors' mode. Did you set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' header in the API response to allow PUT requests?

Comment: did you remove the WebDAV HTTP module?

Comment: @GabrielBitencourt didn't know that about Postman! Yes, I edited my API code so you can see it. As I was telling you, it already works with GET, POST, DELETE

Comment: @pixelbits I don't know what is the WebDAV HTTP module, how should I remove it, is it part of angular ?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro hmmm, let's see. Try changing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin' from * to your actual origin address. I'm not sure why, but I think some browsers don't accept * as the origin

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to change my http request for dont use '/' in the final of request, this problem is only for PUT

```
return $http.put(config.apiUrl + '/cit/product/', product);
```

To this

```
return $http.put(config.apiUrl + '/cit/product', product);
```